# Ordinal logistic regression with a categorical predictor: choosing contrasts

Tags: r, ordinal-data, glmm, ordered-logit

I am fitting an ordinal logit model in brms (STAN and R), to model the effect two predictors over a 5-points ordinal scale. My predictors are two ordinal scales themselves (5-points and 3-points).

Initially I used Helmert contrasts, a popular approach in many regression models for continuous outcomes (http://www.clayford.net/statistics/tag/helmert-contrasts/), where the average of a certain level is compared with the average from the previous levels. The model provides me with the following output:

```
Group-Level Effects: 
~PrimaryArticle (Number of levels: 22) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
sd(Intercept)     1.92      0.46     1.19     3.01       1589 1.00

Population-Level Effects: 

             Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
Intercept[1]    -5.95      0.67    -7.30    -4.71       1545 1.00
Intercept[2]    -2.65      0.61    -3.90    -1.50       1508 1.00
Intercept[3]     1.20      0.60     0.03     2.39       1479 1.00
Intercept[4]     4.28      0.64     3.02     5.58       1424 1.00
IS_PrimArt1      0.65      0.56    -0.50     1.67       1590 1.00
IS_PrimArt2      0.77      0.34     0.07     1.40       1527 1.00
IS_PrimArt3      0.84      0.34     0.13     1.51       1500 1.00
IS_PrimArt4      1.28      0.41     0.49     2.07       1578 1.00
CS_PrimArt1     -0.01      0.45    -0.90     0.93       1296 1.00
CS_PrimArt2     -0.56      0.39    -1.30     0.24       1670 1.00
```

And with the following marginal effects:

[image]

Then, I also fit another model, where I did not specify any contrast, but treated predictors as ordered factors (https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-r-for-finance/factors-4?ex=8).

This model provides me with some changes in its outputs, compared to the previous one:

```
Group-Level Effects: 
~PrimaryArticle (Number of levels: 22) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
sd(Intercept)     2.64      0.61     1.67     3.98       1524 1.00

Population-Level Effects: 
             Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
Intercept[1]    -5.17      0.73    -6.62    -3.76       1483 1.00
Intercept[2]    -1.89      0.67    -3.21    -0.56       1624 1.00
Intercept[3]     1.93      0.68     0.65     3.31       1574 1.00
Intercept[4]     4.96      0.73     3.57     6.46       1590 1.00
IS_PrimArt.L     1.78      1.00    -0.25     3.76       1395 1.00
IS_PrimArt.Q    -0.19      0.80    -1.75     1.43       1569 1.00
IS_PrimArt.C    -0.14      0.82    -1.78     1.45       1558 1.00
IS_PrimArtE4     0.20      0.75    -1.26     1.64       1479 1.00
CS_PrimArt.L    -0.52      0.79    -2.05     1.07       1617 1.00
CS_PrimArt.Q    -0.20      0.70    -1.50     1.25       1785 1.00
```

These changes are probably even clearer, in terms of marginal effects:

[image]

I do not understand how this second model handles contrast in an ordered logit framework. I have these questions:

- why do I have some changes compared to Helmert contrasts?
- which one of the two approaches is the most desirable one (and why)?
- is there any difference between the two models, in terms of statistical power?

Thanks for your suggestions. There are few (clear) resources for applied scientists about ordered logit models.

Jacopo Cerri

Comment: There is now the alternative to use [`brms`](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) to fit ordinal regression with monotonic predictors. See for example the [Estimating Monotonic Effects with brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_monotonic.html) vignette.